# How to install Tensorflow in Raspberry pi 4b 8gb , i am aslo try but getting this error . plese give some good suggestion, how to install?

Tags: python, tensorflow

from tensorflow import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
from tensorflow import keras

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hkCS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Tensorflow lite on Raspberry pi.

TensorFlow Lite with Python is great for embedded devices based on Linux, such as Raspberry Pi.

```
python3 -m pip install tflite-runtime
```

Follow the instructions mentioned https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python